# How to deal with error: Too many open files in system?

Tags: php, linux, shell, cron

I am running a cron and output coming to my id and getting below as output:

> /bin/sh: /usr/bin/php: Too many open files in system

Cron runs every 5 mins.

Have checked `/var/logs/cron` and cron is executed every 5 mins.

Sites are working fine on the server.

Comment: contact your server administrator, I bet you don't have root access

Answer (score 9):

This means your system ran out of file handles, either in your php or in another application. Make sure to [close](http://php.net/fclose) any files you open to free file handles.

To the number of handles of every program running, use (as root):

```
for p in $(ps -A -o pid); do
    nh=$(ls /proc/$p/fd  2>/dev/null | wc -l) &&
    exe=$(readlink -f /proc/$p/exe  2>/dev/null) &&
    echo "$p ($exe): $nh"
done
```

For a more verbose output, use `lsof`.

You can also increase the number of possible system file handles by modyfing [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_limits.html) (which effects changes to [`/proc/sys/fs/file-max`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt)), and decrease it for the current terminal session with `ulimit -n`.

Comment: +1 In addition might be open processes. See http://docs.php.net/pclose

Comment: @fyr Clarified. Is the new version accurate?

Comment: @phihag: yes i removed also my post to keep the answers less redundant

Comment: @fyr Your answer was actually quite good, and I see no detriment in having multiple answers focus on different parts of the solution. Incorporated some good parts.

Comment: When I checked messages log I found, ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value and script name,I checked memory_limit =256 MB in php.ini

Comment: Would be great if this sorted by the number of open files.

Answer (score 0):

Check how many files you have currently open in the system by:

```
$ sysctl kern.num_files
```

and what is your kernel limit by:

```
$ sysctl kern.maxfiles
```

To check which regular files are open, this command can help:

```
lsof | grep -w REG | less
```

If your limit is too low, then increase it by these commands (run as root):

```
sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480
sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=4096
```

<sup>Note: Add `sudo` if required if running from the user account.</sup>

and try again.

To set it permanently, add it into your `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kern.maxfiles=20480
kern.maxfilesperproc=4096
```

If you don't have access to change the limits, contact your hosting provider.